# Make a template out of a WPF ListView and add it to a dll?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, dll, datatemplate

I have a ListView in my WPF applicaiton, that works great with a LOG class. The LOG class would work alone, and when using it I could just copy the classes and the ListView to my new project, but I would rather make a dll that I just reference in the new project.

I have the LOG class in a new library project, own namespace and everything.

How do I get the ListVIew to a template in the dll that I can then use again by referencing the dll?

In short, my ListView looks like:

```
<ListView stuffs="stuff" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:LOG.LogList}, Mode=OneWay}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:AutoScrollToLastItemBehavior /> <!-- Gonna put this class into the dll too -->
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- Many stuffs with stuff -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

So instead of copy-pasting the whole thing, I'd like to reference that dll and then go `<ListView ItemTemplate=Logger/>` or something.

**Edit:** I've tried to simply put the LIstView as it is now into a `<UserControl>`, but that didn't seem to work properly. VS always sais I'm using Binding although it's not a markup extension.

**Edit 2:** So Bindin is indeed a markup extension, I just needed that System.Xaml reference. Now I gotta find out why my Binding Source=... pretends my LOG class, which Intellisense actually suggested, doesn't exist in that namespace. After that, only like 7 red lines to go.

Answer (score 0):

Either (there are probably more methods to do this):

1) Wrap your ListView into a UserControl and then use the control, but you'll have to expose ListView's properties (all of them...) you want to bind to as DependencyProperties, e.g.:

```
public partial class EditableTextBlock : UserControl
{
    [Bindable(true)]
    public TextAlignment TextAlignment
    {
        get { return (TextAlignment)GetValue(TextAlignmentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextAlignmentProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextAlignmentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        ((EditableTextBlock)null).GetMemberName(x => x.TextAlignment),
        typeof(TextAlignment),
        typeof(EditableTextBlock),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata()
        {
            DefaultValue = TextAlignment.Center,
            Inherits = true
        });
 //....
}
```

.

```
 <TextBlock TextAlignment="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:EditableTextBlock}, Path=TextAlignment}" />
```

If you use nuget package [AutoDependencyProperty.Fody](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoDependencyProperty.Fody/), you can in most cases simplify DependencyProperty definition to:

```
    [AutoDependencyProperty(Options = FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault)]
    public TextAlignment TextAlignment { get; set; }
```

2) Create CustomListView class that inherits from ListView and load the template from e.g. resource dictionary and set other properties in the constructor